# How do I remove outlook cached mode and OST file for users with existing mail profiles?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, cached-exchange-mode

We're a citrix shop, and we've got hundreds of persistent Windows 7 VMs out there mostly running Office 2010 Pro, with disk sizes from 45GB to 100GB each. Ideally, we like Outlook to be set up to not use cached mode from the get-go, but often times its missed during user setup. Anybody know of a way to do this after-the-fact? That is, take outlook out of cached mode and remove the associated OST files and ensure they do not get re-created... given the number of machines it would be nice to be able to do this silently and remotely.

Comment: Are they all on the same domain and complies with group policy? Change the group policy. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179175.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - you can use psexec to kill the outlook.exe process, and OST file. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: The VMs are all on the same domain, the users are not.... yet. Thank you for that technet article link! However, it seems that the cached mode group policy is set for users and not machines. It'd be nice to set it for specific computer OUs, since we want to allow laptops to use cached mode, we don't care about physical desktops at the moment, and VMs are in their own OU.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... here's the answer to my question:

The associated reg key for cached mode for Outlook 2010 & beyond is:
“HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles" CachedModeValueName="00036601"

But that varies too much from user to user because there is a different key for each mail profile.

The best way to do it is in fact group policy, and although it is a user policy loopback user policy allows user policy to be applied to a computer OU which will apply to users on those computer resources and take precedence over inherited user policy. We can create a user policy within VDI OU with the "Do not allow an OST file to be created" enabled and "Use Cached Exchange Mode for new and existing Outlook profiles" disabled using ADM templates for Office 2010. This policy will apply to any users logged onto computers within that OU only.

Thanks for everyone's input!